# Creating custom Object3D class

Tags: javascript, class, three.js, extend

I'm new to THREE.js coming from an AS3/Away3D background. I'm trying to create a custom object class that extends THREE.Object3D to add to my scene. CustomObject will encapsulate a lot of behavioural properties and methods. Ideally I'd like to pass each CustomObject it's own data object which will determine how it will look/move/behave. Encapsulating this code will keep my main.js a lot cleaner.

My problem is I can't seem to add an instance of the class directly to my scene. I can only add the mesh via the CustomObject.getMesh() method. Is it possible to add an instance of the class directly to my scene to render? Here's a very basic attempt I've put together from what I've been able to find online and in the /src:

```
function CustomObject(){

    THREE.Object3D.call( this );
    this.type = 'CustomObject';
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 540, 540, 14 );
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ) );
}

CustomObject.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Object3D.prototype );
CustomObject.prototype.constructor = THREE.Object3D;

CustomObject.prototype.getMesh = function(){

    return this.mesh;

}
```

I'd like to be able to add the CustomObject class directly to the scene to make object management a lot cleaner. Can anyone tell me how this is achievable please?

Many thanks in advance!

David

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to add your custom object to the scene directly, you can use a pattern like this one:

```
function CustomObject() {

    this.type = 'CustomObject';

    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 540, 540, 14 );
    this.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );

    THREE.Mesh.call( this, this.geometry, this.material );

}

CustomObject.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Mesh.prototype );
CustomObject.prototype.constructor = CustomObject;

CustomObject.prototype.getMesh = function() {

    return this.mesh;

}

var foo = new CustomObject();
scene.add( foo );
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks WestLangley! Works perfectly and makes complete sense. I was close with the alternate approach but it's working great now. Cheers!

Comment: Which solution did you select?

Comment: Ah ok, I've accepted now, sorry about that. I used the first approach as the second approach threw me this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined', which I couldn't resolve. It was the way I was trying to do it before. But the first approach you offered works fine so I'll stick with that for now. Thanks again for you help!

Comment: The 2nd solution worked for me, but I did not like it, so I deleted it.

Comment: @WestLangley Is it possible achieve the same thing using ES6 classes ?